# How to make :hover more mobile friendly and accessible?

Tags: css, user-interface, mobile, sass, user-experience

I'm using SCSS to make [a dropdown menu](http://jsfiddle.net/ztLbuawy/). Here is an excerpt of how it works:

```
li {
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: $menuBG;
    color: $menuColor;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    &:hover {
        background: $hoverBG;
        color: $hoverColor;
    }
```

Now what I'd really like is for it to do the same thing while still allowing it to work for those without a mouse (people with accessibility clients and mobile phones.) Using jQuery is not impossible but not preferred.

Comment: Use `:focus` in addition to `:hover` to trigger your state change: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/click-function-for-hover-states-on-touch-devices/

Comment: UX / accessibility thought: how does `:hover` work if you use the keyboard because you can't use the mouse?

Comment: @ToniLeigh That's the exact issue I'm trying to fix. It doesn't.

Comment: as you point out haha, don't necessarily reject javascript if it can solve the problem in a more usable way. usability > not using js for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I do not recommend using dropdown menus for anything that's intended to be used on touch (so nowhere, really). But if you want to try to make it work anyway, you could try:

- Use JS to open the menu on `touchstart` and close it on `touchstart` outside the menu
- Use both `:hover` and `:focus` so the menu will open when clicked on (CSS only)
- Or for a more reliable but much trickier CSS-only solution, you could try maybe `anchor` elements with `::after` pseudo elements and the `:active` and `+` selectors -- which will be quite tricky

Comment: What are the alternatives?

Comment: Well, it depends a lot on how much content your page is going to have. A [side-panel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tHLqozJ1tE) with sub-categories is the most widely used design-choice these days. For mobile put a menu button, which slides the panel open.